# In 'Dark Water' and 'Death in Heaven' where is 3W?

Tags: doctor-who

Well, this point is never explained in either of the final two episodes of the 8th season of *Doctor Who*, and I was wondering how

> did Danny get there in 'Death in Heaven' to save Clara?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's 3W not W3 and it seemed quite clear where it was. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

3W is an institute. The headquarters are apparently inside St. Paul's Cathedral.

Danny and the other dead people are stored in the "nethersphere", a Time Lord Hard Drive.

The rain from the exploded cybermen formed a shell around Danny's corpse, and his mind was reuploaded to this — making him come back and able to save Clara.

Comment: Great. Your second sentence answers my question. I just didn't know if 3W was on earth or somewhere else. I'll edit the title to fix the name.

Comment: i don't remember a shell appearing around Danny in the morgue  and the only shells i remember seeing was the UNIT Monitors on Boat One showing active graves (ones which have converted corpse)

Comment: @Memor-X shell as in the cyberman exoskeleton. Not the "egg"s.

Comment: Also, the 3w institute was bigger on the inside. The Doctor remarked that was *easy for a Time Lord*.